# Is it really necessary to remove the complete listener Firebase Authentication?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

As my title says, is it necessary to remove the complete listener or to pass **`this`** as the first parameter in order to remove the complete listener attached to the `signInWithCredential` function?

```
auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, ...)
```

If yes, how can I remove the listener without passing **`this`**?

Comment: pass null. Maybe

Comment: What's the purpose of passing `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to remove the listener.  In fact, it's not possible to remove a listener that was added to a Task returned by an asynchronous operation.  By passing `this` (which I assume means your current Activity), you are telling the Task API that you don't want to handle the result of the sign in after the activity is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you for helping me again. I don't know what I have done without you.